How do I convert an existing folder to a project/solution in Microsoft Visual Studio 2022?
I have a folder containing subfolders and C++ scripts. This folder contains subfolders like, Modules, Tools, Data etc. I was programming writing codes on Notepad ++ and I was compiling and running it through a bash script (.sh) on Ubuntu. I would like to move this program to real IDE, such as Microsoft Visual Studio, so I want to convert this folder to a solution in order to have all MVS functionalities.
I am a beginner with MSV, so I do not know all its basic functionalities and I might use non-suitable words. I tried to do File -> New -> Project from existing code. In this way I loose my subfolders structure and it provides me so many errors. Of course, I was not able to run it because I could not set a startup item. Is there an easy and immediate way to convert an existing folder to a MVS project/solution? I think that in order to run it some setting must be done, for example the "translation" of the bash scripting.
